# Surviving Mars - Employment issue

Tags: surviving-mars

Is the game at the end unbalanced?

At the "end", you can enhance your work places so that less people need to work there, while I got a big population, and now less jobs.  Resulting in my people becoming depressed for being unemployed.

So to make my people happy again, I removed this enhancement, so they had a job again.

I loved playing Surviving Mars, but this seemed a bit unbalanced to me.

Answer (score 6):

Did you noticed the Workshop Milestone ?

> 40% Workers in Workshops

This should give you a clue.

The Workshops are basically useless factories that use resources and produce... nothing.
https://survivingmars.paradoxwikis.com/Dome_buildings#Dome_Services
(OK, I'm lying, they produce comfort and morale).

Their main purpose is to give (air quotes) "jobs" to your unemployed population, and helping you finding the perfect equilibrium between production and employment.

And once you found this perfect equilibrium, the birth control option is here to ensure your population stays at that level.

With the correct breakthroughs, I imagine you can put 80 to 90% of your population in those workshops. Creating the perfect utopia (except for those 10% still needing to work).

Comment: That is true, but... my original question remains:  Why would you want to enhance your work places, so that less people would need to work there.  While you basically need workplaces at the same time, since both occur nearly at the end.

Comment: The way I see it, Workshops are not primarely a way to give something to do to your unoccupied population. The Workshops are the end game objective you want to implement. Trying to get that last milestone that will give you this achievement feeling.